# Can i use only one table for all hibernate envers auditing?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, playframework, hibernate-envers

i recently found the beautiful library that is called "hibernate envers", it's such a great and easy way to have an audit log, it solved one of my biggest problem while working on a play web-application.
Now, i know that Envers use one table for each audited entity, and want to know if it is possible to have one table for every thing? (using a varchar to put all the data for example and put the entity model in a separate column)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is not possible. Only table-per-entity strategies are available currently (Default and ValidityAuditStrategy).

See the manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html